# WordPress fuel plugin how to call ajax actions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have installed the wordpress fuel plugin. By this I have created a plugin to list the property.

Here I have integrated one ajax call like this

In my view file i use this below code:

```
        $('#collapse3').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"<?php  echo $plugin->dispatchRequest("saleshome/index",array('lat' => $latitude,'lng'=>$longitude)); ?>",
            data: { },
            success: function(data){
                $('#collapse3_res').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

By using this code, it is not working. I don't know how to write this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax code like this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#collapse3', function() {
    var data = { };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"<?php  echo $plugin->dispatchRequest("saleshome/index",array('lat' => $latitude,'lng'=>$longitude)); ?>",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            $("#collapse3_res").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript add in wp_footer hook on function.php
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);


bellow wp_ajax hook add on function.php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

    // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
    wp_die();
}
```